# How to recover Neo4J 3.0 database from transaction log?

Tags: neo4j

After an accidental `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE (n)`, is it possible to restore the database using the transaction log?
I believe my `graph.db/neostore.transaction.db.0` represents the complete transaction history of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.0/tools/src/main/java/org/neo4j/tools/applytx/DatabaseRebuildTool.java is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please elaborate on how to use the DatabaseRebuildTool

Answer (score 3):

To partially apply transaction logs you can use the DatabaseRebuildTool as mentioned above until version 3.4. The tools were made private in commit [f2ceb1a5](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/f2ceb1a598f7103231198454a78c24c887cedbc3).

To use the RebuildTool you can follow the steps below (tested on Windows for 3.3.9).

A fork with the changes in version 3.3 can be found [here](https://github.com/timo92/neo4j/commit/69f973b2c3cbc14df6fc3b731836cabe351a3e18).

- clone [neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j.git)
- checkout the required version
- modify tools\pom.xml to include an execution for DatabaseRebuildTool (copy one and change class to org.neo4j.tools.applytx.DatabaseRebuildTool, replace id and fileName with dbrebuild)
- build neo4j according to the instructions given in the Readme for your version
- cd to tools
- duplicate checkTxLogs.bat and rename to dbrebuild.bat
- Change class in dbrebuild.bat to match DatabaseRebuildTool to org.neo4j.tools.applytx.DatabaseRebuildTool
- Run dbrebuild.bat with required args, or no args to print help (may take some seconds)

  `dbrebuild.bat --from path\to\graph.db --to path\to\new.db -i --overwrite-to`
- apply transactions up to desired transaction id or latest (help, exit)

  `apply last`

Note: before starting neo4j with the new database you have to exit the dbrebuild process as only one process may access the database at a time.